# "no enclosing instance of type file1 is in scope" error with inner classes

Tags: java, inheritance, inner-classes

I have some code (essentially it imports this other class which has an inner class which I'm trying to access), but it brings up this error:

```
file2.java:5: error: no enclosing instance of type file1 is in scope
    public static class file3 extends file2.Inner {
```

What does "no enclosing instance of type file1 is in scope" mean?

Here is the code:

```
package test;
import secret.file1;

public class file2 extends file1 {
    public static class file3 extends file2.Inner {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            file3 outer = new file3();
            System.out.println(outer.x);
        }
    }
}
```

file1's code:

```
package secret;

public class file1 {
    protected class Inner {
        public int x = 8;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll admit I'm not 100% sure about the error message, but I see 2 issues with your code: 1) You don't define a nested static class named `Inner`, so how can you extend it?  Your IDE should be coughing up red flags on `extends file2.Inner`.  2) You're missing a main method.  You've got a method named `main()` in `file3`, but one of the defining features of a main method is that it must be in a top-level class, so Java will not recognize that as the main method.

Comment: @user15358848 You're right, I was thinking of inner classes, but `file3` is a nested class, not an inner class.  My bad.

Comment: @user15358848, I changed it to extends file1.Inner but that doesn't seem to fix the error. I also edited the post to include the file1 class if that's any help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## The Problem

You're trying to make a nested class a subclass of an inner class, and that is practically not possible the way you've done it.  There is a way to do it, see Savior's answer for the syntax, but in your situation, it doesn't help you.  The key difference between a nested class and an inner class is that an inner class is tied to a specific instance of the outer class, whereas a nested class isn't tied to any particular instance.  To illustrate this difference, let's modify your code a bit:

```java
public class file1 {
    private int x;

    public file1(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    // No static keyword, so this is an inner class:
    protected class Inner {
        public void printXInner() {
            // This is legal:
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }

    // Has static keyword, so this is a nested class:
    protected static class Nested {
        public void printXNested() {
            // This is NOT legal:
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
}
```

The `printXInner()` method is perfectly legal because `Inner` is tied to a specific instance of `file1`, so it can access the instance-specific (non-static) field `x`.  However, the `printXNested()` method will throw a compile-time exception, because it doesn't know *which* `x` you want to use.  You could have lots of instances of `file1`, and each instance could have a different value for `x`.

Now, why is this important, and how is it relevant to your code?  Well, let's say Java just decided to allow what you're trying to do; you can extend inner classes.  If we're still using the modified code above, we could write something like this:

```java
public class file2 extends file1.Inner {
    public void printXFile2() {
        printXInner(); // Uh oh, what should the program do here?
    }
}
```

This code seems perfectly harmless, it extends `Inner` and it calls the `printXInner()` method.  Except our old problem comes up again: *which* `x` should it print?  We haven't specified which instance of `file1` to use.  So you're essentially trying to use an inner class in a static context.

---

Now, hopefully you're thinking "Okay, I understand why there's a problem, but how do I fix it?"  You've basically got two options: you can change your inner class to be a nested class, you can change your `file2` class to be an inner class.  Which option you choose will depend on the structure of your code.  You need to decide if you want `Inner` to be tied to a specific instance of `file1` or not.

## Fix #1

Change the inner class to be a nested class.  This is the way to go if you don't need to access instance-specific data from your nested class.  Maybe you have a car class, and you want to have a nested class for the wheels.  If we're talking about this in the sense of a car parts store, the wheels aren't attached to any car, so we don't want our nested class to be attached to any instance of the outer class.  Simply modify `file1` like so:

```java
public class file1 {
    // Added static keyword:
    protected static class Nested {
        public int x = 8;
    }
}
```

## Fix #2

Make the subclass extend the inner class of a specific instance of the superclass.  This is the way to go if you need to access instance-specific data from your inner class.  Maybe you have a car class, and you want to have an inner class for the wheels.  If we're talking about this in the sense of a driving simulator, then the wheels are attached to a specific car and they stay attached.  Hence, we want our inner class to be attached to a specific instance of the outer class.  Simply modify `file3` like so:

```java
public class file2 extends file1 {
    // Removed static keyword:
    public class file3 extends Inner { ... }
}
```

This may create a secondary problem, though.  You can't have a main method inside an inner class, because at startup, there are no instances of the outer class, so the JRE can't call a method of the inner class.  A workaround is to put the main method in the outer class, and call a method on a specific instance from there.  You could implement this like so:

```java
public class file2 extends file1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new file2().file3.doSomething();
    }

    public class file3 extends Inner {
        public static void doSomething() {
            file3 instance = new file3();
            System.out.println(instance.x);
        }
    }
}
```

## TL;DR

Inner classes are different from nested classes.  Inner classes are bound to a specific instance of the outer class, while nested classes are not bound to any particular instance.  You cannot reference an inner class without specifying an instance, because that goes against the definition of an inner class.

Comment: @Savior Okay, so I've read your answer, and you're right, there is syntax to support a nested class extending an inner class.  That said, I don't see why you would want to use it.  By requiring the enclosing instance parameter, you are requiring that `file3` is bound to an instance of `file2`, which is exactly what would happen if you just made `file3` an inner class.  Why write all that extra fancy code when you could achieve the *exact same* result simply by removing the static keyword?  It would be different if `file2` was not a subclass of `file1`.

Comment: @Savior I've called this out as a caveat to the first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

### For educational purposes only, do not use in practice.

Inner classes have this unique behavior where all their constructors **implicitly** declare a parameter of the enclosing type in the first position. So,

```
public class file1 {
    public class Inner {
    }
}
```

is actually compiled to something like

```
public class file1 {
    public class Inner {
        public Inner(file1 enclosing) {
        }
    }
}
```

where `enclosing` is actually a reference to the enclosing `Outer` instance it was initialized from.

```
new file1().new Inner();
// compiles to something like
file1 enclosing = new file1();
new Inner(enclosing);
```

Remember that with regular inheritance, if the superclass declares a parameterized constructor (and no parameterless constructor), the subclass has to use `super(...)` to call it in its own constructor. With inheritance of inner classes, that `super(...)` call can be done **implicitly** if an enclosing instance was also provided **implicitly**.

That is, your class hierarchy would've compiled if `file3` was actually also an inner class of `file1` (or `file2`), rather than a nested class.

```
public class file2 extends file1 {
    public class file3 extends file2.Inner {
    }
}
```

As I said before, `file3` will compile to something like

```
public class file3 extends file2.Inner {
    public file3(file2 enclosing) {
        super(enclosing); // this is calling the `public Inner(file1)` constructor
    }
}
```

The `super(..)` call would've been done **implicitly** because an "enclosing instance of type `file1` is in scope".

However, because your `file3` class is not an inner class of `file1` nor `file2`, there is no **implicit** enclosing `file1` instance to pass to the super constructor and so the Java compiler produces the error you see.

I keep bolding the word **implicitly** to try and highlight the fact that Java lets you bypass all this **explicitly**. This feature is unique to inner classes. Java provides the following syntax to declare the constructor with a parameter (in any position) to **explicitly** be considered the enclosing instance

```
public static class file3 extends file2.Inner {
    public file3(file2 enclosing) {
        enclosing.super(); // special syntax
    }
    // [...]
}
```

And, just like regular inheritance, that `super(..)` call has to be the first statement in the constructor body.

Your `main` method then becomes something like

```
file2 file2 = new file2();
file3 outer = new file3(file2);
System.out.println(outer.x);
```

where you explicitly provide what's meant to be the enclosing instance required by `file2.Inner` (could also have passed `null`).

---

For your information, there's also syntax to **explicitly** declare the constructor I mentioned in my second snippet, with the parameter representing the enclosing instance

```
public class file1 {
    public class Inner {
        public Inner(@SomeAnnotation file1 file1.this) {
        }
    }
}
```

This is really only useful if you want to annotate the parameter.

This information is spread across [Chapter 8 of the Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-8.html), in particular in sections about "inner classes" and "receiver parameters".